# Feedback to 'please write a script for me' questions?

Tags: support, scope, questions

Recent example: [auto-fill for new values in google spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/auto-fill-for-new-values-in-google-spreadsheets)

Downvoting is one thing, voting to close as too broad maybe? But both these don't give feedback to the user so that (s)he can learn how to write better questions and/or improve the question.

*This is not a script writing service* is a bit unfriendly boiler plate text.

**Can anyone recommend a good feedback text for these script requests**?

(BTW I do note the occasional answer to these kinds of questions. Please don't do that, it'll only teach new users that these kinds of questions are OK to ask).

Answer (score 2):

On recent questions from new contributors that hasn't an answer yet, I frequently use the following:

`Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].`

On very few cases I add something like

`If you didn't read {url} yet please do it now, then [edit] your question to make it more specific by describing where do you got stuck`

Sometimes I also include links to related questions.

By the way, if the question is updated by Community usually I downvote this kind of questions and vote the answers accordingly to their content, if they are quality answers or I learn something from them I up-vote them, but if they just include a cryptic formula / script I down vote them.

Answer (score 1):

There are some questions that instead of being voted to close as too broad it could be more convenient **to be closed as a duplicate**<sup>1</sup>.  In such cases, besides voting it as close as duplicate, we could leave a comment as

`Welcome. Please checkout the posible duplicate question. If you need further help, please edit your question to make your question specific and to add a brief description of the efforts you made so far or were did you get stuck`

NOTES:

1. We already have a lot of questions that have an answer with a formula / script. If the question is clear besides that it doesn't mention the OP efforts made but it was already answered, IMHO, it *should* be closed as duplicate

Related

- [What question should be used (or set) as the canonical question for questions about split/transpose column values?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4710/88163)