# What question should be used (or set) as the canonical question for questions about split/transpose column values?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

We have "yet another" question about "data transformation" in [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) that is about having a column filled with values separated by a character that should be split & transposed while keeping the relation integrity with the other values on the same original row.

The question is [Format data inserted from google form in sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135318/88163) (this question was deleted)

Despite that this question doesn't include at this time a description of the **search** efforts made by the OP, I think that this question could be marked as duplicate of another question, but...

IMHO opinion we already have a lot of related questions and I'm not sure which of them, if any, could be used to mark this question as a duplicate of (by question ID order):

- [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60861/88163)
- [How to split then combine data to rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78279/88163)
- [Convert jagged array to 2D array in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91412/88163)
- [Convert the data from comma-separated cells into repeated rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95635/88163)
- [Split multi-line (comma-separated) cell into new rows + duplicate surrounding row entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123876/88163)
- [Split comma-separated cell in sheets while repeating other cell for all entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/134992/88163)

Recently I got the gold badge for [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) but before using my
privilege I would like to know if anyone have a suggestion or concern

---

Other related (just split without the keeping the relation integrity with other values on the same original row)

- [Split text with Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56508/88163)
- [Split a column of strings with a single formula returning an array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88517/88163)

---

Related Meta Questions

- [Feedback to 'please write a script for me' questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/88163)

Comment: The problem is twofold, in some cases it is necessary to use a [script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78279/how-to-split-then-combine-data-to-rows). In others a formula (although [sometimes complex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56508/split-text-with-google-sheets)) is sufficient.        People are looking for a ready-made solution rather than making the effort to look for it on their own. ([please write a script for me](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/feedback-to-please-write-a-script-for-me-questions))

Comment: Questions that doesn't include any mention of an effort made by the OP *should* be voted to be closed as unclear / too broad / duplicate. I think that on cases like this that there is already a solution on this site, the question should be closed as duplicate, then if the OP needs further help, they could edit their question or post a new one.

Comment: Okay, we can extend this particular case of `split/transpose` to every first time users asking a question to get a script done. [tag:google-apps-script] is polluted with [this kind of behavior.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134771/writing-a-macro-to-create-a-new-tab-and-name-that-tab-based-on-a-cell-value-in-g) These kind of answers :
`I was hoping that someone could propose a piece of code that I could use in my file.`

 @Rubén, I admire your kindness and patience.

Comment: @pjmg I'm offering a bounty (see my answer or just go to the Bountied tab on the main page)

Answer (score 1):

The oldest question looks to be

[Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60861/88163)

IMHO, besides it's the oldest one, it's good as a faq because it already include several well received answers, some include scripts, other include formulas, by the other hand it already is linked to other eight questions.

I'm offering a bounty on this question to request a canonical answer.