# What to do with questions about unpivot / flattening data using Google Sheets?

Tags: discussion, tags, canonical-question

We have several questions about passing data from a *double entry table* to a *simple table shape*.

By *double entry table* I'm referring to something like this

| Item | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | 20 | 15 | 18 |
| Vase | 7 | 5 | 9 |

By *simple table* I'm referring to something like this

| Item | Month | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | January | 20 |
| Chair | February | 15 |
| Chair | March | 18 |
| Vase | January | 7 |
| Vase | February | 5 |
| Vase | March | 8 |

- There are 52 posts that have the word [flatten](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=flatten), 46 of them has [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
- There are 10 posts that have the word [unpivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=unpivot), 3 of them are questions which 2 of them has [unpivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unpivot) (it hasn't a tag excerpt & wiki), both have [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets). The other question has [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online).

There are other posts about the same "task" that neither *unpivot* or *flatten* were included. Below some examples:

- [How to combine dynamic columns in Google Sheets while retaining data in other rows?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125232/88163)
- [Analyse multiple columns per row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129597/88163)
- [How to convert repeating rows into columns in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143165/88163)
- [Transpose multiple columns into single column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150080/88163)
- [How to sum a range columns from another google sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/151290/88163)

I'm wondering if we should make a mini-retag project starting by adding a tag excerpt to [unpivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unpivot) and / or select some questions as canonical.

Comments, thoughts, suggestions or concerns?

Related

- [What question should be used (or set) as the canonical question for questions about split/transpose column values?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4710/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the basic case having one column for n row headers, one row for m column headers and n by m values it's very likely that the best will be to have a canonical question. Some questions that belongs to this case, from older to newer:

- [Flatten (pivot) table into a three column array on a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51481/88163)

  - It has no linked questions yet.
- [Turn a table into a list of row/column/value tuples](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76563/88163)

  - It's linked to 2 questions. None of theme are duplicates.
- [Transpose Ranges repeated by row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115804/8816)
  It's already linked to 7 questions, but not all them are duplicates.
  Duplicates:

  - [Transform a Google Spreadsheet table? Columns by rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119603/88163). It belongs to other case as it's about having two columns for row headers.
  - [Create row for each entry in a table (ideally without script)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153057/88163)
- [Restructure (flatten) data of Google Sheets table in a new table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/144147/88163)

  - It has no linked questions yet.

I'm still not sure what existing question should be used as a canonical question. Suggestions?

---

Case having two column headers OR two row headers (with no blank / merged cells). Some questions that belong to this case:

- Two rows for column headers, one column for row headers

  - [Displaying specific column header for cells, based on the cell value and its row header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/139146/88163)

Case having tow column headers OR two row headers with blank / merged cells. Some question that belong to this case:

- [Transpose multiple columns into single column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150080/88163)